# Lua - What is the most optimized method of a Lua function?

Tags: loops, optimization, lua

I searched before I ask my question.
I have two method to make a loop. And I wonder what the two is the more optimized. And may be you can find better.
The goal is to loop every 1 seconds. This already works.

Thank you to time to explain. Which one is the best. Before proposing a third option.

- My method 1:

  ```
  content=0
  function loop1()
      content=content+1
  end

  timer.Create("myloop",1,0,function() loop1() end)
  ```
- My method 2:

  ```
  content=0    
  Table={
      loop1=function()
          content=content+1
      end
  }

  timer.Create("myloop",1,0,function() Table:loop1() end)
  ```

  ---

Edit:

- My method 3:

  ```
  content=0    
  timer.Create("myloop",1,0,function() content=content+1 end)
  ```

Legend:
0 in timer.Create = infinit loop.
1 in timer.Create = launch the function, 1 per second.

The contents of the function is simplified by something that does not seem to be helpful to the base. But what interests me is the basic method.

Comment: Aside from the unnecessary wrapping in a function, you're optimizing prematurely -- there is little point in trying to shave cycles off something that only runs once per _second_.

Comment: Sorry english is not my native language. If I understand, The content is to simplify my request. the real content it is big just to understand a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the function in a table gains you nothing and forces an extra table lookup.

Adding the extra wrapping (unnamed) function in the `timer.Create` call is also not a useful thing to do as it just adds an extra function calls overhead to the process.

Using locals is always better than using globals.

Something like the following is likely the best:

```
local content = 0
local function loop1()
    content = content + 1
end

timer.Create("myloop", 1, 0, loop1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I like to do experiments. I apply it immediately.
Thank you for the same opportunity to edit my post.
There is a performance difference of writing this way?

Comment: This small bit of code is probably as good as you can get it but as @BenGrimm said in the comment on the op this smells awfully like premature optimization. The likelihood of this mattering in the long run are slim-to-none especially once your function does anything of any actual usefulness.

Comment: I dont know other method.
Legend: 0 in timer.Create = infinit loop. 1 in timer.Create = launch the function, 1 time per second.

The contents of the function is simplified by something that does not seem to be helpful to the base. But what interests me is the basic method.

Comment: The point that BenGrimm was making was that unless you know that the difference between these two choices is going to make a difference to your running time this sort of discussion/check is not very useful. The chances of this difference mattering in the real program is very unlikely because the real work being done is likely to far outweigh the difference here.

Comment: I needed to save a maximum of resource. Before I used Method 2.
and my loop is a loop of 0.1 seconds. Not really one second. I wanted to keep it simple when I posted. your answer helped me to make the difference. I apply all that can be optimized. I have edited my old system and not use function stored in table called by another function. I think it's always better than the old system.